# Make normality t test with list item

Tags: r, lapply, t-test

I need do test t for this data, but "lapply" generates a variable in the list, and within this list it is necessary to get some specific information, normality and statistics for each column [,1]

```
library(igraph)
vetor <- c(1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 9, 3, 2:15, 1, 5, 3, 6, 5, 9, 3 )
matrixnet<-matrix(vetor, 7, 7)
matcor <- cor(matrixnet, method = "spearman")

matrixnetwork = graph.adjacency(matcor, mode="undirected", weighted = TRUE, add.colnames=NULL, diag=FALSE)
plot(matrixnetwork)

##Boot
N <- 7L
set.seed(2023)
R <- 100L
BIPERMUT<- vector("list", length = R)
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
  indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE)
  BIPERMUT[[i]] <- permute(matrixnetwork, sample(vcount(matrixnetwork)))  
}

plot (BIPERMUT[[1]])
degree(BIPERMUT[[1]], normalized = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
matrix
#degree analyse
boot_degree2 <- lapply(BIPERMUT, degree, normalized = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
#Statist
shapiro.test (boot_degree2)
t.test(boot_degree2,mu = 0)
```

this is show:

```
shapiro.test (boot_degree2)
```

> Error in shapiro.test(boot_degree2) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE

```
> t.test(boot_degree2, mu = 0)
```

> Error in var(x) : is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
> Além disso: Warning message:
> In mean.default(x) : argumento não é numérico nem lógico: retornando NA

Comment: This code isn't very helpful to replicate the problem, but are you maybe looking for `lapply(boot_degree2, shapiro.test)`?

Comment: I edit cod. See please! I will run your surgestion

Comment: This form i try, but the shapiro.test is run to each line, but I need shapiro.test run for columns (7 columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do

```r
sapply(boot_degree2, 
    function(x) unlist(shapiro.test(x)[c("statistic", "p.value")]))
```

(you might want to transpose the result), and a similar function for `t.test()`. Both `t.test()` and `shapiro.test(0` return an object of class `htest`, which is a list including (at least) elements "statistic" and "p.value".

(As a side point, I'm not sure either of these tests makes much sense statistically, but that's not what you asked ...)

---

If you want to run these tests nodewise/columnwise:

```r
dmat <- do.call("rbind", boot_degree2)
## apply tests columnwise
apply(dmat, 2,
    function(x) unlist(shapiro.test(x)[c("statistic", "p.value")]))
```

As before, this fails because *all* of the degrees in the matrix are equal ...

Comment: This form I try, but the shapiro.test is run to each line, but I need shapiro.test run for columns (7 columns) not lines... I have 7 columns and 100 lines, It's run for lines (permutation results )

Comment: This form run! Perfect, thanks for help!